# Rocket how to specify body for Outcome::Failure?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I want to specify a response body in the Failure Outcome of AuthenticatedUser.

I tried implementing Responder for AuthError but it didn't do anything. It compiled successfully, but `respond_to` was never called, instead the error was propagated to the default catcher.

If I were able to pass a string from the outcome to the error catcher that could also be a solution, but I couldn't find a way to do that either. The only information I can pass is the status code.

Perhaps I could have a global hashmap that maps status codes to response messages. Since rocket stores status codes as a u16 I have 65536 - 500 = 65036 status codes to represent all possible response messages. But that would be a very "hacky" solution, and I don't want to go down that route.

I'm using rocket 0.5.0-rc.3

auth.rs

```rust
pub struct AuthenticatedUser {
    pub id: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum AuthError {
    NoHeader,
    IncorrectHeader,
    InvalidToken,
}

impl<'r> Responder<'r, 'static> for AuthError {
    fn respond_to(self, request: &'r Request<'_>) -> rocket::response::Result<'static> {
        let body = "test".to_owned();
        Response::build()
            .status(Status {
                code: 523,
            })
            .sized_body(body.len(), Cursor::new(body))
            .ok()
    }
}

#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for AuthenticatedUser {
    type Error = AuthError;

    async fn from_request(req: &'r Request<'_>) -> Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        let mut auth_headers = req.headers().get("Authorization");
        let auth_header = auth_headers.next();

        let Some(header) = auth_header else {
            return Outcome::Failure((Status::Unauthorized, AuthError::NoHeader))
        };

        let parts = header.split("Bearer ").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        if parts.len() != 2 {
            return Outcome::Failure((Status::Unauthorized, AuthError::IncorrectHeader));
        }
        let token_str = parts[1];
        let public_key = &keys().public_key;
        let validation = Validation::new(Algorithm::RS256);
        let decode_result = decode::<Claims>(&token_str, &public_key, &validation);

        let Ok(token) = decode_result else {
            return Outcome::Failure((Status::Unauthorized, AuthError::InvalidToken))
        };

        Outcome::Success(AuthenticatedUser {
            id: token.claims.user_id,
        })
    }
}
```

catcher.rs

```rust
use rocket::{Catcher, http::Status, Request, catcher::BoxFuture, response::Responder};

#[catch(default)]
pub fn handler<'r>(status: Status, req: &'r Request<'_>) -> &'static str {
    "{
        \"error_code\": \"UNKOWN\",
        \"message\": \"An unkown error occurred.\"
    }"
}
```

Comment: tip: You can use raw string literals to avoid having to escape all the `"` of json: `r#"{"error_code": "UNKNOWN",...}"#`

Answer (score -7):

You're aiming to manage error instances within a Rocket application and issue appropriate custom responses. In Rocket 0.5, you may utilize `request::Outcome::Failure` in conjunction with `catch`, however, you have to return a type that puts into practice `Responder` as opposed to merely the `Status` and `AuthError` tuple.

Below is a demonstration of how you can accomplish this via enclosing your `AuthError` within a struct that exercises `Responder`:

```rust
pub struct AuthErrorResponse {
    pub status: Status,
    pub error: AuthError,
}

impl<'r> Responder<'r, 'static> for AuthErrorResponse {
    fn respond_to(self, request: &'r Request<'_>) -> rocket::response::Result<'static> {
        // Map AuthError into specific status code and error message here
        let error_message = match self.error {
            AuthError::NoHeader => "No header",
            AuthError::IncorrectHeader => "Incorrect header",
            AuthError::InvalidToken => "Invalid token",
        };

        // Create JSON response
        let response = json!({
            "error_code": self.status.code,
            "message": error_message,
        });

        // Build response
        Response::build()
            .status(self.status)
            .header(ContentType::JSON)
            .sized_body(response.to_string().len(), Cursor::new(response.to_string()))
            .ok()
    }
}

// Alter return type of from_request to AuthErrorResponse
#[rocket::async_trait]
impl<'r> FromRequest<'r> for AuthenticatedUser {
    type Error = AuthErrorResponse;

    async fn from_request(req: &'r Request<'_>) -> Outcome<Self, Self::Error> {
        // Adjust error cases to return AuthErrorResponse instead of tuple
        let mut auth_headers = req.headers().get("Authorization");
        let auth_header = auth_headers.next();

        let Some(header) = auth_header else {
            return Outcome::Failure(AuthErrorResponse {
                status: Status::Unauthorized,
                error: AuthError::NoHeader,
            })
        };

        // ...
        // Same for other error cases
    }
}
```

In this way, when you return `Outcome::Failure`, Rocket will have the capacity to convert your `AuthErrorResponse` into a proper HTTP response with a custom body, rather than simply sending a status code and descending into the default catcher. You don't need to use the catcher for this particular case, unless you intend to manage other general errors within your application.

Comment: This, and your other answers, look like ChatGPT